# How to connect docker container with the machine where it was launched?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a ethereum node launched in the machine and i need to interact with it from the container. In other way, I need to invoke the blockchain node from the container.

Comment: can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: The short answer if you need to access your hosts' loopback interface, is: You can't. The long answer is: you could with a reverse proxy on the host.

Comment: Please update the same information in question.

Comment: You can start the container with host network driver and then it runs on the same network as your host.